# How can I hide "Use of mozImageSmoothingEnabled is deprecated." notification in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I am currently trying to develop something in js and some library I use somewhere probably causes this warning. It keeps popping up messing my console log where I am trying to debug in and I don't want to see it anymore. Is there a way to ignore this?

> Use of mozImageSmoothingEnabled is deprecated. Please use the unprefixed imageSmoothingEnabled property instead.

Answer (score 0):

It could be true by default so try adding this using the multiple cross-browser attribute variations:

`ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;`
`ctx.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;`
`ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;`
`ctx.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;`
`ctx.oImageSmoothingEnabled = false;`